# Disabling Angular Materials 2 Animation During Protractor Test

Tags: angular, protractor

Angular Version 5.2.3

New to Protractor and Angular and having trouble with setting up the test. I could only imagine this may be due to an animation issue slowing down the test since the test passes sometimes. Maybe I need to take a different approach, but the goal is to see if I can sort a table. Is there a way to disable the animations? I've tried using [element.all(locator).allowAnimations](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.allowAnimations) which throws an Angular is not defined error.

```
it('should sort full name column', async () => { // ignoring for now until figure out a way to wait until table sorts
await listUserPage.navigateTo();

await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(listUserPage.userTable));
const unsortRows: string[] = [];
const sortRows: string[] = [];

// get all values of full name column
await listUserPage.tableRows.each(async (row) => {
const col = row.all(by.tagName('mat-cell')).get(0);
  unsortRows.push(await col.getText());
});

// sort in order we expect
unsortRows.reverse();

await listUserPage.clickFullNameSort();
await listUserPage.clickFullNameSort();   // need to click twice, once for asc then again for desc
await browser.driver.sleep(500);

await listUserPage.tableRows.each(async (row) => {
  const col = row.all(by.tagName('mat-cell')).get(0);
  sortRows.push(await col.getText());
});
```

Comment: Can you post the exact text of the error?  Is Protractor set to wait for Angular or did you bypass that?

Comment: You might just create a new environment for E2E testing (thanks to angular-cli) and define an env variable `noAnimations` to true in that env, false in others. Then in your module, based on that variable include the real animation module or the NoopAnimationsModule

Comment: BUT... I'd strongly advise you to use cypress instead of Protractor anyway...